# How can I use attributes of items inside a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to access attributes of items in my DataFrame.
Here is what I got so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index = [0, 1]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['time', 'timedelta'], index=index)
df.time = pd.Timestamp('2022-04-07 22:10:00'), pd.Timestamp('2022-04-07 22:11:00')
df.timedelta = np.timedelta64(df.time[0].hour), np.timedelta64(df.time[1].hour)
print(df.timedelta)
```

But I need to scale the conversion to timedelta up. I can't call it via its index anymore.

I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index = [0, 1]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['time', 'timedelta'], index=index)
df.time = pd.Timestamp('2022-04-07 22:10:00'), pd.Timestamp('2022-04-07 22:11:00')
df.timedelta = np.timedelta64(df.time.hour)
print(df)
```

I get the following error message:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epr80.png)

But I can't get it to work.

Comment: show the actual error message

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use `pd.to_timedelta` directly, note you need to use `.dt` method to access date time properties:

```
pd.to_timedelta(df['time'].dt.hour, unit='h')
```

Output:

```
0   0 days 22:00:00
1   0 days 22:00:00
Name: time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```